# How to get reason for exception in web service

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, exception, tomcat6

How could I get cause of exception that occurs in my web service? (I have jsf 1.2 project and two other projects that I should as web service) I have web service that when  get called should do some reading from database and return string as a result, but when ever I try to do it I get following error (BioskopBean method is calling method from web service):

```
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:acer-PC

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.majkicservis.bioskop.BioskopSoapBindingStub.getFilmove(BioskopSoapBindingStub.java:115)
at com.majkic.bioskop.BioskopBean.prikaziFilmove(BioskopBean.java:74)
at com.majkic.bioskop.BioskopBean.<init>(BioskopBean.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:406)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:215)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:199)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:68)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:614)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1145)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:451)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:77)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:816)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:983)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:234)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:180)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:127)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:840)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:840)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

P.S. I tried to make other web service that just returns string and it works but in project above I can't find out what is causing this error

Comment: I think the problem is that you are reaching the server at all. Check that the calls indeed goes to the server.

Comment: I tried to call method in web service and pass some parameter and return that same value and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

When interpreting a stack trace, a good starting point is to skip calls to external libraries and find the code that you wrote.

```
com.majkicservis.bioskop.BioskopSoapBindingStub.getFilmove(BioskopSoapBindingStub.java:115)
```

From there, something your code is calling threw a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, which means that it's trying to access a bean property that doesn't exist or whose bean doesn't implement Serializable.  Are you expecting an object to be read or written to with the property "hostname"?

Comment: or may be that the native library files needs R/W/X access by Tomcat (or the web account being used for the hosted site)??